xskak. A chessboard with dotted lines programmatically
I have a problem - I need a dashed or dotted arrow on the chessboard. (When I am printing in black and white this is the best to distinguish between lines)
There is no such style naturally. I am trying this and it works
\chessboard[
    setfen=r1bqkbnr/pp1ppppp/2n6/2p5/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQKB1R b KQkq - 1 2,
    addpgf={\tikz[overlay]\draw[red,line width=0.1em,->,dashed](f1)--(b5);},
]

but this addpgf would not work in a setup where I want to use newCommand to wrap the chessboard and remove repetition (otherwise code is unreadable and ugly).
I am trying smth along following lines and can't make it work because \tikz and \draw are expanded too early. Would you possibly be able to give and advice?
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\markChessboard}[1]{%
    % Initialize a temporary macro to store moveid and markmove pairs
    \def\pastmoves{}%
    
    % Iterate over each move identifier in #1 and append to \pastmoves
    \foreach \x [count=\ni] in {#1}{%
        \xskakset{moveid={\x}}%
        \xdef\pastmoves{\pastmoves \tikz[overlay]\draw[red,line width=0.1em,->,dashed](\xskakget{movefrom})--(\xskakget{moveto});}%
    }

    % 
    
    % Now call \chessboard with the accumulated \pastmoves 
    \chessboard[
        addpgf={\pastmoves}
    ]
}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5}
\markChessboard{1w, 1b}

\end{document}

and I get
! Undefined control sequence.
\tikz@deactivatthings ->\def ;
                              {\tikz@nonactivesemicolon }\def :{\tikz@nonact...
l.27 \markChessboard{1w, 1b}
                            
? 


Expanding \tikz is not going to be a good idea. I don't see why you need to prepare the \pastmoves, you can just use one tikzpicture and use the loop to do the actual work (→ Code A).
I will also move this code to its own macro so the addpgf statement looks more neatly if this is your concern.
You could also prepare a macro just the connections, in Code B I'm using an edge so that this can later be used one one path.
You could also prepare a foreach list of movefroms and movetos to iterate over in it but I don't see the advantage over Code A really.
Code A
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak, tikz}
\newcommand*\markChessboardLoop[1]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
  \foreach\x[count=\ni]in{#1}{%
    \xskakset{moveid=\x}
    \draw[red, line width=0.1em, ->, dashed]
      (\xskakget{movefrom})--(\xskakget{moveto});}
  \end{tikzpicture}}
\newcommand*\markChessboard[1]{\chessboard[addpgf=\markChessboardLoop{#1}]}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5}
\markChessboard{1w, 1b}
\end{document}

Code B
\usepackage{xskak, tikz}
\newcommand*\markChessboard[1]{%
  \gdef\pastmoves{}%
  \foreach\x[count=\ni]in{#1}{%
    \xskakset{moveid=\x}%
    \xdef\pastmoves{\pastmoves(\xskakget{movefrom})edge(\xskakget{moveto})}}%
  \chessboard[addpgf={\tikz[overlay]\path[red, line width=0.1em, ->, dashed]\pastmoves;}]}
\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5}
\markChessboard{1w, 1b}
\end{document}

Output


Well you can define your own style. But as currently chessboard uses pgfpicture and not tikzpicture you have to use the basic commands which isn't really comfortable. I have therefore decided to switch to tikzpicture. So with the next version (in a few days) style definitions will be easier.
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{xskak}
\makeatletter
\cbDefinePgfMoveStyle{dashedmove}{%
    \pgfsetlinewidth{\board@pgf@linewidth}%
    \setlength\len@board@tempx{\dimexpr 0.1em + \board@pgf@shortenstart \relax}%
    \pgfsetshortenstart{\len@board@tempx}%
    \setlength\len@board@tempx{\board@pgf@shortenend}%
    \pgfsetshortenend{\len@board@tempx}%
    \pgfsetarrowsend{\board@pgf@arrow}%
    \pgfsetdash{{2pt}{4pt}}{0pt}% %<----
    \pgfsetroundcap
    \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpointorigin}%
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}%
    \pgfusepath{stroke}}%
    
%with next version:    
\cbDefinePgfMoveStyle{moveto}{\draw[->,#2](0,0)--(#1);} 
        
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\newchessgame
\mainline{1.e4 e5}
\chessboard[    
    pgfstyle=dashedmove,
    markmove=e2-e4,
    ]
%with next version 2.0   
\chessboard[    
    pgfstyle={[red,very thick,dashed]moveto},
    markmove=e2-e4,
    ]

\end{document}


